# Python: Why does user input to text file gets forgotten by my program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

This may sound a little confusing but I am trying to create a program that can ask a user for a name, store that input in a text file and then check future user inputs to see if that name is in the file

I have it working for one run i.e. input 1 name, and can check that name is in file.

But when I try to do a different name, it completely 'forgets' about the first name.
Any ideas? Thanks
(code, file and output provided)

Code:

```
HeroName = ""

while HeroName != "Quit":
Hero = open("HeroHolder2.txt", "r+")
HeroName = input("Name a hero: ").title()

if HeroName in open("HeroHolder2.txt", "r+").readlines(): #checks to see if input is in file already
    print(HeroName + ", is in database")

elif "Quit" in HeroName:
    Hero.close()
    quit()
elif "Clearholder" in HeroName: #makes the file new again
    Hero = open("HeroHolder2.txt", "w")
    print("Handbook cleared")

else: #Writes name to file if not already there
    with open("HeroHolder2.txt", "a+") as Hero:
        print("Hero invalid - adding to data base")
        Hero.write("\n"+HeroName)
```

Output:
[Output to Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3TLH.png)

Text File:
[What the text file shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvKPF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readlines()` reads the ending newlines but your enter name has no newline. Replace:

```
if HeroName in open("HeroHolder2.txt", "r+").readlines():
    print(HeroName + ", is in database")
```

with:

```
if HeroName in [line.strip() for line in open("HeroHolder2.txt", "r+").readlines()]:
    print(HeroName + ", is in database")
```

Comment: Yes it does work thank you so much! - Sorry any chance you could explain how it works to further my understanding?